# unstable zero solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

How can I choose the function $U$ , where $U(0)=0$ and $\dot U$ is positive definite for the system:

$$\dot x=y+xy^2$$
$$\dot y=x+yx^2$$

Because I want to show that the zero solution of the given system is unstable.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! On this site it is usually recommended that you post what you have tried so far on the problem so that answerers may help address your specific problem, rather than just serve as a place to get solutions to homework exercises.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get instability more easily by using the symmetry of the ODE. Namely, let $z=z(t)$ (scalar function) be the solution of $z'=z+z^3$ with $z(0)=\epsilon$. Clearly, $z$ increases with time and tends to infinity. Since $(z(t),z(t))$ is a trajectory of the given system with initial point $(\epsilon,\epsilon)$, it follows that $(0,0)$ is unstable.

Comment: In what sense is $z(t)$ a trajectory of the given system?

Comment: @RobertLewis Not $z(t)$, but $(z(t),z(t))$. That is, $x=y=z$; both equations in the system are satisfied.

Comment: @ Post No Bills:  OK, I see what you're saying.  Thanks.